# How to query this get the result by same value in column have exit in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select a.*, b.haydung 
from CTMAUBOCVATTU a, vattu b  
where a.mavt = b.mavt
```

This are two sample screenshots from this query:

[image]

This result is **Ok** .

[image]

This second result is **not OK**.

I want to get the list row same name: MADDK have condition exit 1 or column have value haydung=1

```
SELECT 
    a.MADDK, a.MAVT, a.NOIDUNG, a.SOLUONG, a.GIAVT, a.TIENVT, 
    a.GIANC, a.TIENNC, b.haydung
FROM 
    CTMAUBOCVATTU a
JOIN 
    vattu b ON a.mavt = b.mavt
WHERE 
    a.MADDK IN (SELECT MADDK
                FROM CTMAUBOCVATTU
                WHERE haydung = 0)
    AND b.haydung = 1
GROUP BY 
    a.MADDK, a.MAVT, a.NOIDUNG, a.SOLUONG, a.GIAVT, a.TIENVT, 
    a.GIANC, a.TIENNC, b.haydung
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 0;
```

This is my query but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CTMAUBOCVATTU]
(
    [MADDK] [varchar] (11) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [MAVT] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [NOIDUNG] [nvarchar] (3000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [SOLUONG] [decimal] (18, 2) NULL,
    [GIAVT] [decimal] (18, 0) NULL,
    [TIENVT] [decimal] (18, 0) NULL,
    [GIANC] [decimal] (18, 0) NULL,
    [TIENNC] [decimal] (18, 0) NULL,
    [ISCTYDTU] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CTMAUBOCVATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MAUBOCVATTU] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MADDK], [MAVT]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CTMAUBOCVATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CTMAUBOCVATTU_MAUBOCVATTU] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MADDK]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MAUBOCVATTU] ([MADDK])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CTMAUBOCVATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MAUBOCVATTU_VATTU] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MAVT]) REFERENCES [dbo].[VATTU] ([MAVT])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VATTU]
(
    [MAVT] [varchar] (20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [MAHIEU] [nvarchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TENVT] [nvarchar] (500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [DVT] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [GIAVT] [decimal] (19, 0) NULL,
    [GIANC] [decimal] (19, 0) NULL,
    [NGAYAD] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [MANHOM] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [HAYDUNG] [bit] NULL,
    [MANVN] [varchar] (10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [THUEVAT] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_VATTU] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MAVT]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VATTU_DVT] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([DVT]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DVT] ([DVT])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VATTU_NHANVIEN] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MANVN]) REFERENCES [dbo].[NHANVIEN] ([MANV])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VATTU] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VATTU_NHOMVATTU] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MANHOM]) REFERENCES [dbo].[NHOMVATTU] ([MANHOM])
GO
```

Comment: Not really understand what you are asking here. But sounds like you need to use [exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please paste in as text only. Sample data as well as the logic required and your attempt so far would help immensely.

Comment: The first thing I see is that the condition `HAVING COUNT(*) = 0` will never be true. A group cannot exist unless it has at least one defining row. Can you better explain in words what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to retrieve all rows having a MADDK value where at least one row with the same MADDK value has haydung = 1.

In your first data set, the second row has haydung = 1, so all rows with MADDK = 150 should be selected. In your second data set, no rows have haydung = 1, so rows with MADDK = 50DTD100 should not be selected.

How about:

```
SELECT a.MADDK, a.MAVT, a.NOIDUNG, a.SOLUONG, a.GIAVT, a.TIENVT, a.GIANC, a.TIENNC, b.haydung
FROM CTMAUBOCVATTU a
JOIN vattu b ON a.mavt = b.mavt
WHERE a.MADDK IN (
  SELECT a2.MADDK
  FROM CTMAUBOCVATTU a2
  JOIN vattu b2 ON a2.mavt = b2.mavt
  WHERE b2.haydung = 1
);
```

There may be better ways of writing the above using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) or window functions, but I believe the above should accomplish the task without getting overly complicated.

Comment: i want get all row but in same mddk exits haydung=1  one or more row

Comment: I just realized that `haydung` was a part of the `vattu` table, so have updated the answer above to include it in the subselect. Please give it another try.